# Retrieve previous version of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, version-control

I have modified a stored procedure today but after that I realized that it is wrong. So I want revert it back. Is there any way to get the previously modified stored procedure or else last date's stored procedure.I don't have any back up also. Thank you.

Comment: Yes - retrieve its previous state from your source control system......

Comment: Which front-end did you use? Maybe the front-end you used (SSMS) keeps history or temporary files in some system temp folder.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly within SQL Server.  Unless you have kept a script in source control or elsewhere your only option is to restore an older backup to another environment and script out the old version from that.

Comment: You're pretty much buggered then.  If that is the case you will have to reconstruct the previous version by hand.

Answer (score 3):

No, unless the SSMS query window you used to alter the procedure still has the old text in its undo buffer. You must restore a backup copy and manually transfer the procedure from database copy.
You shouldn't be updating the database directly, but use a [version controlled script](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/) instead to start with.

In future you can also install tools like the [SSMS Toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Download.aspx) that keep a history of every query you've run.

Answer (score 1):

Have you any backups of the database itself? The stored procedure is part of the database. Restore it onto a spare machine and extract it from there.

If you don't have a backup of the database... huh???